# Null checker in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have `resData` object with `Courses` listItem and `Error` property. I have checked all the `Courses` list item `Error` properties and all of them are `null`.

However, when I check in the following, it returns `true`.

I wonder what I am missing?

```
if(resData.Courses.Select(x => x.Error != null && x.Error.Length > 0).Count() > 0)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Comment: FYI, this could just be replaced with: `resData.Courses.Any(x => x.Error != null && x.Error.Length > 0)`  or even simpler in C# 6 > `resData.Courses.Any(x => x.Error?.Length > 0)`

Comment: Or even `resData.Courses.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Error))` assuming that `Error` is a `string`.

Comment: @juharr good eye, I assumed it was not a string

Comment: @juharr - one has to be careful using methods such as that in LINQ when using it to interact with a DB (such as LINQ to SQL or EF code).  `string.IsNullOrEmpty` cannot be translated to SQL and you will get errors telling you as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are using a `Select`, you are projecting your collection, not applying a condition, you should use `Where` instead, or use an overload of `Count` method:

```
if(resData.Courses.Count(x => x.Error != null && x.Error.Length > 0) > 0)
```

And as @Chris pointed out, it's better if you use `Any` to avoid enumerate the entire list:

```
if(resData.Courses.Any(x => x.Error != null && x.Error.Length > 0))
```

Comment: Or better yet use `Any` to save having to go any further through the collection than needed (`Where` and `Count` will bother enumerate the entire list).

Comment: It's true guys, I'm going to add that, I was trying to explain why that happened to him/her first

Comment: Yup. I wasn't meaning to imply the answer wasn't already good (and you had my +1 already for spotting the error and explaining it), just felt it could have that little cherry on top too. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Chris, highly appreciated 